# Different results with Binomial Probability, what is the correct?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I was searching a way to calculate the binomial probability by code, and I found these two calculators online by they return different results.
Which is the correct one and why?

Example params:
p=0.5
n=18
k=14

https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx

http://www.ciphersbyritter.com/JAVASCRP/BINOMPOI.HTM#Binomial

[image]

Comment: excel gives $0.011673$ for $P(X=14)$.

Comment: so the correct is the second one, can you tell if the first one is wrong or maybe is doing something else that I didn't note?

Comment: Something must be wrong with the first. No idea what exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given data of $(18,.5,14)$  the correct answer for $pdf$ is $$0.011672974$$
And for $cdf$ is $$ 0.996231079$$

Comment: OK so the first page is wrong? but that looks so strange, I mean they are selling courses about statistics, and the binomial probability is very simple, I feel the probability of not understanding the page is higher than an error is in that page :/